# SElinux: allow httpd to connect to a specific port

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, selinux, redis

My system is running CentOS 6.4 with apache2.2.15. SElinux is enforcing and I'm trying to connect to a local instance of redis through my python/wsgi app. I get Error 13, Permission denied. I could fix this via the command:

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect`

However, I don't exactly want httpd to be able to connect to all tcp ports. How can I specify which ports/networks httpd is allowed to connect to? If I could make a module to allow httpd to connect to port 6379 ( redis ) or any tcp on 127.0.0.1, that would be preferable. Not sure why my paranoia is so strong on this, but hey...

Anyone know?

Comment: Would it not be better to force it to go out through a proxy? That way you can a) have better control over what can be accessed b) have better auditing over what happened and when.

Answer (score 63):

By default, the SELinux policy will only allow services access to recognized ports associated with those services:

```
# semanage port -l | egrep '(^http_port_t|6379)'
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
# curl http://localhost/redis.php
Cannot connect to redis server.
```

- add Redis port (6379) to SELinux policy

```
# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 6379
# semanage port -l | egrep '(^http_port_t|6379)'
http_port_t                    tcp      6379, 80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
# curl http://localhost/redis.php
Connected successfully.
```

You can also install `setroubleshoot-server` RPM and run: `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log` - it will give you a nice report with useful suggestions (including command above).

PHP script to test connection:

```
# cat redis.php 
<?php

$redis=new Redis();
$connected= $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

if(!$connected) {
        die( "Cannot connect to redis server.\n" );
}

echo "Connected successfully.\n";

?>
```

Comment: I had the problem on Fedora 23 to send e-mail (by connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 25) from a perl script (using Net::SMTP) started from httpd. "Permission for httpd to connect to port 25" is not what one is looking for in that case. Indeed adding port 25 to SELinux type `http_port_t` fails because port 25 is already used (for another SELinux type): `ValueError: Port tcp/25 already defined`. The correct way to allow httpd to connect to port 25 is to set the corresponding SELinux policy boolean on: `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on` (see `getseebool -a`). (continued in part 2)

Comment: (continued from part 1) But if you want to send from a perl script, you have to explicitly create a SELinux module that allows that: `sealert -b; sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log; grep perl /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol; semodule -v -i mypol.pp`. Then it works!

Comment: @DavidTonhofer  Minor typo in the `getsebool -a` command (one fewer `e`).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer you don't have to create a new policy for existing port, you can modify it instead: `semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 25`, see `semanage port --help`

Comment: For zabbix, there already is a specual boolean on CentOS 7.5: `setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_zabbix true`

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful in adding another port for postfix to listen to: semanage port -a -t smtp_port_t -p tcp 2525

Comment: How to restrict this change only to one specific user? I have different apache users for each website and don't want to open Redis port for each user.

Answer (score 23):

You may need to use

```
semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 6379
```

If semanage is missing then add the package policycoreutils-python

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```

Comment: `semanage` may be in `policycoreutils-python-utils` now (at least on Fedora 23)

Comment: CentOS 7 still includes `semanage` in `policycoreutils-python`.

Comment: thank you for giving an answer to the question instead of something else.

Answer (score 3):

You could temporary put selinux in permissive mode and let httpd connect to redis, then generate and build a custom policy module using **audit2allow**