# SELinux context for apache ldap ssl

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ldap, selinux

## Question

What SELinux context do I need, for what file to get apache ldap (over ssl) auth to work? Or is it a network protocol or system call or something else entirely?

## Environment

Apache 2.4 on Centos 7 using basic ldap authentication over ssl.

With SELinux permissive (`setenforce 0`), everything runs well and fine. I can log in to the protected directory with ldap perfectly.

When SELinux is enabled (`setenforce 1`), apache cannot perform the ldap search and allow the user through. It has something to do with ssl or certificates and I can't figure it out.

**/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log**

```
[Thu Mar 17 15:33:32.529755 2016] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 6412] mod_authnz_ldap.c(501): [client 158.158.193.232:17386] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldaps://ldap-ad.example.org:636/ou=Auto-Accounts,dc=example,dc=org?sAMAccountname?sub
[Thu Mar 17 15:33:32.530792 2016] [ldap:debug] [pid 6412] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Thu Mar 17 15:33:32.531845 2016] [ldap:debug] [pid 6412] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Thu Mar 17 15:33:32.532936 2016] [ldap:debug] [pid 6412] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.
[Thu Mar 17 15:33:32.533568 2016] [authnz_ldap:info] [pid 6412] [client 158.158.193.232:17386] AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user bgstack15 authentication failed; URI /auth1/ [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Can't contact LDAP server]
[Thu Mar 17 15:33:32.533784 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 6412] ssl_engine_io.c(992): [client 158.158.193.232:17386] AH02001: Connection closed to child 1 with standard shutdown (server sample.example.org:443)
```

**/var/log/audit/audit.log**

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1458243341.951:1234): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=6428 comm="httpd" dest=636 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldap_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1458243341.951:1234): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=12 a1=7f2c0498eab0 a2=10 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6409 pid=6428 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1458243341.952:1235): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=6428 comm="httpd" dest=636 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldap_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1458243341.952:1235): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=12 a1=7f2c0498eab0 a2=10 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6409 pid=6428 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1458243341.952:1236): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=6428 comm="httpd" dest=636 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldap_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1458243341.952:1236): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=12 a1=7f2c0498d580 a2=10 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6409 pid=6428 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1458243341.953:1237): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=6428 comm="httpd" dest=636 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldap_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1458243341.953:1237): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=12 a1=7f2c0498d580 a2=10 a3=0 items=0 ppid=6409 pid=6428 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

#### What I've tried already

I have started reading up on SELinux and have tried copying the context from other certificates. I tried doing that on the certificates in /etc/openldap/certs and also /etc/pki/tls/certs.
Perhaps I need to try something for the tcp port 636?

#### Updates

[SElinux: allow httpd to connect to a specific port](https://serverfault.com/questions/563872/selinux-allow-httpd-to-connect-to-a-specific-port) provides a working solution, but it is not refined for maximum security yet.
The command

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on
```

allows httpd to perform the ldaps bind. However, this opens up httpd too much so I am still looking for a way to allow just port 636.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's always the boolean `httpd_can_connect_ldap`.

This allows:

```
# sesearch -b httpd_can_connect_ldap -AC
Found 1 semantic av rules:
DT allow httpd_t ldap_port_t : tcp_socket name_connect ; [ httpd_can_connect_ldap ]
```

And `ldap_port_t` provides access to the relevant ports:

```
# semanage port -l
ldap_port_t                    tcp      389, 636, 3268, 7389
ldap_port_t                    udp      389, 636
```

Comment: For all you google-copy-pasters, the exact command is `setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap on`. (edited to include Michael's info below)