# SElinux: allow httpd to connect to redis

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redhat, selinux, redis

I'm running on RedHat7, with apache 2.4 and redis installed. Apache won't connect to redis unless selinux issues are resolved. I know that one option to fix that is to allow all connections with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

but I'd rather only allow connections to redis, which is running locally, instead of all tcp ports. I followed the suggestions in:

[SElinux: allow httpd to connect to a specific port](https://serverfault.com/questions/563872/selinux-allow-httpd-to-connect-to-a-specific-port)

but it didn't quite work for me. The first suggestion failed because the redis port is already defined (by redis):

```
 semanage port -l | egrep '(^http_port_t|6379)'
 http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
 redis_port_t                   tcp      6379, 16379, 26379

 semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 6379
ValueError: Port tcp/6379 already defined
```

The second suggestion:

```
 semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 6379
```

worked, and apache was able to connect to redis properly. Though, after a reboot, redis didn't want to start, giving me another selinux error ("SELinux is preventing /opt/rh/rh-redis32/root/usr/bin/redis-server from name_bind access on the tcp_socket port 6379"):

```
SELinux is preventing /opt/rh/rh-redis32/root/usr/bin/redis-server from name_bind access on the tcp_socket port 6379.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests     
If you believe that redis-server should be allowed name_bind access on the port 6379 tcp_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
 Do allow this access for now by executing:
 ausearch -c 'redis-server' --raw | audit2allow -M my-redisserver
 semodule -i my-redisserver.pp
Additional Information:

Source Context                system_u:system_r:redis_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0
Target Objects                port 6379 [ tcp_socket ]
Source                        redis-server
Source Path                   /opt/rh/rh-redis32/root/usr/bin/redis-server
Port                          6379
```

**Does anyone know how to properly allow apache to connect to (a locally installed) redis, without setting "httpd_can_network_connect"?**

Note: the selinux complaint about httpd not being able to use redis, before doing any semanage commands was:

```
SELinux is preventing /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 6379.
*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (89.3 confidence) suggests   ******************
If you want to allow httpd to can network connect
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_can_network_connect' boolean.
Do
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
*****  Plugin catchall (11.6 confidence) suggests   **************************
If you believe that httpd should be allowed name_connect access on the port 6379 tcp_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd
# semodule -i my-httpd.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:redis_port_t:s0
Target Objects                port 6379 [ tcp_socket ]
Source                        httpd
Source Path                   /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd
Port                          6379
Host                          <Unknown>
Source RPM Packages           httpd24-httpd-2.4.27-8.el7.1.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
[...]
Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1540322412.65:21558): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=26250 comm="httpd" dest=6379 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:redis_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1540322412.65:21558): arch=x86_64 syscall=connect success=no exit=EACCES a0=11 a1=7efca766b050 a2=10 a3=5bcf746c items=0 ppid=11656 pid=26250 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=httpd exe=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
Hash: httpd,httpd_t,redis_port_t,tcp_socket,name_connect
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is revert the port number to its original type, put it in permissive to collect AVCs, then [build the local policy module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow). You can then go back to enforcing.

Comment: Thanks; yes, that's always an option. I was just wondering if there was a less "hand made" way of doing it. I got optimistic when I saw the other post (that "almost" worked for me).