# Cannot access apache2 and tomcat running on my ec2-instance

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat

My ec2 ubuntu instance has apache2 working on port 80 and tomcat working on 8080. I'm not able to access them from my browser, i checked the access.log for apache2 it doesn't show the request coming in.

My checklist :

- AWS Security Group , all traffic inbound and outbound enabled.
  [image: AWS Security Group inbound rules]
  [image: AWS Security Group outbound rules]
- Service is running.
  [image: netstat -ntlp]
  [image: service is running]
  [image: telnet 80]
  [image: telnet 8080]
- iptables has no rules initialized.
  [image: iptables]
- No errors thrown by either of the services.
- access log for apache2
  [image]

I've even tried to telnet to my apache2 server.
[image]

The issue started when i added an .WAR package to tomcat

Comment: @kenorb : im able to ssh to the instance

Comment: Similar: [AWS ec2 - open port 8080](http://serverfault.com/q/317903/130437)

Comment: Can you ping it? Is your ssh works when using the same IP?

Comment: @kenorb : Yes i can ping it. and my ssh works fine using the same IP

Comment: Have you checked `80` or `8080` from different host, maybe it's your Windows firewall which doesn't allow you to connect to it?

Comment: @kenorb : i checked, still getting the same issue.

Comment: You could try if the issue is Tomcat specific, then run netcat (`nc -lp 8888 -v`) to listen on `8888`, re-open this port with custom rule and check if that would work. Then re-test from other server, check your firewall `sudo ufw status verbose`, if still doesn't work, then disable your firewall (`sudo service ufw stop`) and re-try. If still doesn't work, maybe test different instance or contact Amazon Support that the added rule doesn't work properly.

Comment: @kenorb : I checked again , even with the firewall down no request's are coming in.

Comment: You tested with netcat (`nc`) on different port? Does it print anything with firewall disabled?

Comment: @kenorb : yes i tested with netcat on different ports, its not printing anything

Comment: @kenorb : solved the issue , just did a forced restart of the instance. Dont know the reason why , but seems to be an AWS issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's great you solved it. If you think it'd happen again, try reporting this as an issue to Amazon, maybe they've some problems.